# How do I force update of translated text when only the substitution value has changed?

Tags: angular, internationalization

In Angular 4 I have a message "n devices selected", where n is substituted. The messages is localized so in the HTML it looks like

```
{{'selected_message' | translate:substitutions }}
```

where 'selected_message' has an entry in the language file:

```
'selected_message': '{{ndevices}} devices selected.'
```

The value of substitutions.ndevices changes frequently. But the translate system does not rerun the translation when substitutions.ndevices changes, so the message always appears to show its initial value. How do I force the translation to rerun?

Things I have tried:

- Making a variable that contains 'selected_message' in the component;
- Resetting that variable to the same thing ('selected_message')
- Setting that variable to empty string and then immediately back to 'selected_message'

How do I do this?

Comment: Is substitutuions variable mutated ? if yes, you should use immutable data so pipes will consider it as new input and re run the transformation... For Example, instead of setting substitutions.ndevices = "something", you should do like substitutions = { ndevices: "someting"}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We should not use mutable objects as input to pipes, because angular checks reference of an object to detect if any input changed, So if property of an object is modified angular will not be able to identify as new input. So in order to avoid this we can use immutable data structure in any form such as immutableJS or for this case as follows,

> Instead of setting property in object like substitutions.ndevices = "something", we should use as substitutions = { ndevices: "something" }

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken you'd like a pipe which is not lazy.

This tweak should solve the problem:

```js
@Pipe({
  name: 'flyingHeroesImpure',
  pure: false
})
```

You can find more on pipes, especially pure and impure ones on https://angular.io/guide/pipes

Alternatively, using an observable which provides you with a stream of data in conjunction with the async pipe in the template would guarantee that your html stays up to date.

Comment: Good info, but I would prefer to use the standard translate pipe.

Comment: Absolutely, you can still use the standard translate pipe. One option would be to find the source code for the translate pipe under node_modules/@angular/common/pipes copy it and modify it to set the pure option to false. That might be a hassle and using impure pipes come with it's own overhead, that's why I'd recommend creating an observable of type selected_message and first piping it through the async in the html. That would produce the desired effect.